# Como retornar vários valores de uma função - flutter/dart?

Tags: funções, flutter, dart

Começo por dizer que este é o meu primeiro post e sou um noob em flutter e dart. Estou a fazer exercicios para um curso e deparei-me com esta dificuldade.

Como retiro vários valores de uma função que vai buscar valores à API do open weather? Já tentei tudo o que sei e não consigo, será que me podem ajudar?

Obrigado

```
  weatherResponse(city) async {
var appid = '13bc3e253e4da17881dac9e55aae947f';

var url = Uri.http('api.openweathermap.org', '/geo/1.0/direct',
    {'q': '{$city}', 'appid': appid});

var geoLockUp = await http.get(url);
if (geoLockUp.statusCode == 200) {
  var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(geoLockUp.body) as List;

  double lat = jsonResponse[0]['lat'];
  double lng = jsonResponse[0]['lon'];

  var url = Uri.http('api.openweathermap.org', '/data/2.5/weather',
      {'lat': '$lat', 'lon': '$lng', 'appid': appid, 'units': 'metric'});

  var responseFinal = await http.get(url);
  var jsonResponseFinal = convert.jsonDecode(responseFinal.body) as Map;

  return jsonResponseFinal;
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

Olá

Primeiramente eu gostaria de te dar algumas dicas, evite o use excessivo de 'var', sempre tente dar os tipos corretos para as suas variáveis, isso pode ser uma boa prática para você começar a praticar.

Voltando ao assunto Dart especificamente não suporta retorno de valores multiplos, porém não é exatamente o que você quer fazer um exemplo que você pode usar, é basicamente retornar um objeto que você pode usar com todos os valores que você precisa

Você pode pegar o valor de retorno em Json e transformar em um objeto em Dart, existem algumas ferramentas que você pode usar como:

[Json to Dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).